# How to use SSL in AWS ec2 without using load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created one EC2 instance and hosted a backend for my application on it
then I want SSL certificate so I follow some AWS tutorials and then use Load balancer to attach that cert to my EC2.

but now that ELB is costing me too much and I want to remove it.

So i need to know how can i attach SSL to my EC2 without that load balancer

Answer (score 0):

You can't use AWS certificates outside of loadbalencers or cloudfront.

You can use letsencrypt to generate a new (free) certificate from your ec2 instance. See https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/

Comment: Not even on an Amazon EC2 instance that's running without a loadbalancer?

Comment: @Qasim - No.  ACM certificate private keys are not available so you cant install the certificates yourself on your servers, they are only available to supported AWS services listed here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-services.html  AWS do provide a "private CA" option - but this is hundreds of dollars a month and designed for big companies - that leaves you with LetsEncypt(free & automatic much like ACM), or any budget certificate provider you can find in a search engine and manually installing the certificate chain files.